# Iterate div tags using lxml and retrieve text for a dictionary in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I just came to know lxmlx in python and I'm in the need for some help as I have no experience with XPath.
I want to get text data from a webpage into a dictionary.

I'm referring to the html snippet I posted below. Within the original html page there's a div element of the class `general-info` that I retrieve using the following line:

```
general_info = document_tree.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'general-info')]")
```

From here on I want to iterate over the nested `div`s and get the 2 `<p>` tags as key and value. The text inside the `<strong>` being the key.
There can also be empty `div` tags and there can be  a special case where the key and the value for the dictionary can be within the same div (see the last element).

**EDIT:**

The number of elements can change, so it would be best to use the `<strong>` tags as starting point and then search for the next `<p>` tag.
This is code that I was able to write using BeautifulSoup:

```
generalinfo = documentSoup.findAll("div", {"class": "general-info"})
if generalinfo:
   strongs = generalinfo[0].find_all('strong')
   for descr in strongs:
        p = descr.find_next_sibling("p")
        if p:
            key = descr.text.strip().rstrip(':')
            details_dict[key] = p.text.strip()

        else:
            nextdiv = descr.parent.parent.find_next_sibling("div")
            if nextdiv:
                child = nextdiv.findChild()
                if child:
                    key = descr.text.strip()[:-1]
                    details_dict[key] = child.text.strip()
```

I am going for the following output:

```
['Title:' : 'This is a title', 
'Owner:' : 'This is an owner',
'Category:' : 'This is a categroy',
'Type:' : 'This is a type',
'Special case:' : 'This is a special case']
```

If anyone can help me out here I will appreciate this!

**html code:**

```
   <body>
      <main>
       <div>
       ...
        <div class="general-info margin-bottom-20 margin-top-20">
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Title:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is a title</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Owner:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is an owner</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="h3 margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10 padding-x-20">Validity</h2>
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Category:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is a category</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-x-40"></div>
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Type:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is a type</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-x-40">
                <div>
                    <strong>Special case:</strong>
                    <p>This is a special case</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is about as generalized as I can get given the html provided:

```
general_info  = doc.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'general-info')]//p[@class='margin-0']")
for i in general_info :
    if len(i.xpath('./strong/text()'))>0:        
        topic = i.xpath('./strong/text()')[0]
    if len(i.text.strip())>0:       
        entry += i.text.replace('\n','').strip()
        print(topic+'   '+i.text.replace('\n','').strip())
special = general_info[0].xpath('./ancestor::div[@class="general-info margin-bottom-20 margin-top-20"]//div/div/strong')[0]
print(special.text+"  ",special.xpath('./following-sibling::p/text()')[0])
```

Output:

```
('Title:   This is a title',
 'Owner:   This is an owner',
 'Category:   This is a category',
 'Type:   This is a type',
 'Special case:   This is a special case')
```

Comment: Thanks! It works in this case! What i forgot to mention was the fact that the number of elements can change. So I was more going for a dynamical solution where for example a `<strong>` tag is searched and then its next corresponding `<p>` tag.

Comment: @tzippy - Well, other than your "special case",  all html blocks look the same. Can you edit your question and show html with a block with a different number of elements? Because I'm not sure now as to what html you are working with.

Comment: I am going over multiple html pages and on other pages there might be more elements than Title, Owner, Category etc. I added code that I wrote using BeautifulSoup, but I would liketo just use lxml instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend another solution, which is very suitable for extracting data from XML.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''
 <body>
      <main>
        <div class="general-info margin-bottom-20 margin-top-20">
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Title:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is a title</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Owner:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is an owner</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="h3 margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10 padding-x-20">Validity</h2>
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Category:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is a category</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-x-40"></div>
            <div class="row padding-x-20">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p class="margin-0">
                        <strong>Type:</strong> 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p class="margin-0">This is a type</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padding-x-40">
                <div>
                    <strong>Special case:</strong>
                    <p>This is a special case</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
'''
data={}
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html) # create doc
divs = doc.selects('div.general-info')
# First way
for div in divs:
  strongs = div.strongs
  for strong in strongs:
    p = strong.next
    if not p:
      p=strong.parent.next
    data[strong.text]=p.text
print(data)
data={}
# Second way
for div in divs:
  ds = div.selects('strong|p>text()')
  for i in range(0,len(ds),2):
    data[ds[i]]=ds[i+1]
print(data)
```

Result:

```
{'Title:': 'This is a title', 'Owner:': 'This is an owner', 'Category:': 'This is a category', 'Type:': 'This is a type', 'Special case:': 'This is a special case'}
{'Title:': 'This is a title', 'Owner:': 'This is an owner', 'Category:': 'This is a category', 'Type:': 'This is a type', 'Special case:': 'This is a special case'}
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/